# html wordle change language

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Guess the 5-letter Country</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <table>
                <tbody id="board">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label for="word" class="user-input">Your Word: </label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="5" minlength="5" id="word">
                <button class="submit">Enter!</button>
            </div>
            <p id="game-over"></p>
            <button class="reset">RESTART!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    const wordList = [
        "شحالك",
        "Egypt",
        "Gabon",
        "Ghana",
        "Kenya",
        "Libya",
        "Niger",
        "Sudan",
        "Chile",
        "China",
        "Haiti",
        "India",
        "Italy",
        "Japan",
        "Malta",
        "Nauru",
        "Nepal",
        "Palau",
        "Qatar",
        "Samoa",
        "Spain",
        "Syria",
        "Tonga",
        "Yemen",] //Yemen is at index 23, when the length of the array is 24

    const randomizeWord  = list => list[Math.floor(Math.random() * (wordList.length - 1))];
    let answer = randomizeWord(wordList).toUpperCase();
    console.log(answer);

    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    const board = document.getElementById('board');
    const textBox = document.querySelector('input');
    const inputContainer = document.querySelector('.input-container')
    const submitButton = document.querySelector('.submit');
    const resetButton = document.querySelector('.reset');
    const gameOverMessage = document.getElementById('game-over');
    console.log(board.children.length);
    const clearBoard = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < board.children.length; i++){
            let currentRow = board.children[i];
            for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                let square = currentRow.children[k];
                square.textContent = "";
                square.classList.remove('incorrect');
                square.classList.remove('correct');
                square.classList.remove('in-word');
            }
        }
    }
    let currentGuessNumber = 0;
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        currentGuessNumber = 0;
        textBox.value = "";
        gameOverMessage.textContent = '';
        answer = randomizeWord(wordList).toUpperCase();
        inputContainer.style.display = 'block';
        console.log('New Answer:', answer);
        body.classList.remove('incorrect');
        body.classList.remove('correct');
        body.classList.remove('in-word');
        body.classList.remove('failed');
        clearBoard();
        textBox.focus();
    })

    const submitGuess = () => {
        let guess = textBox.value;
        textBox.value = "";

        if (guess.length !== 5) {
            return //Do not accept words that are not 5 letters long
        }

        //render guess to the board
        writeGuess(guess)

        currentGuessNumber++

        //check for win
        if (guess.toUpperCase() === answer.toUpperCase()) {
            gameOverMessage.textContent = 'You found the country!!!';
            inputContainer.style.display = 'none';
            return
        } else {
            textBox.focus();
        }

        //check for loss
        if (currentGuessNumber >= board.children.length) {
            gameOverMessage.textContent = `You lost, the country was ${answer}`;
            body.classList.add('failed');
            inputContainer.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    submitButton.addEventListener('click', submitGuess);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        if (e.key === 'Enter'){
            submitGuess();
        }
    });

    function writeGuess(guess) {
        //build our match array so we easily see what matches
        let matchArray = buildMatchArray(guess)
        console.log(matchArray);
        if (matchArray.includes(1)){
            body.classList.remove('incorrect');
            body.classList.add('in-word');
        } else if (!matchArray.includes(1) && !matchArray.includes(2)){
            body.classList.remove('in-word');
            body.classList.add('incorrect');
        } else if (!matchArray.includes(0) && !matchArray.includes(1)){
            body.classList.remove('incorrect');
            body.classList.remove('in-word');
            body.classList.add('correct');
        }
        //identify the current tr tag
        let currentGuessRow = board.children[currentGuessNumber];
        //identify the column for each letter in that row
        let columns = currentGuessRow.children

        for (let i = 0; i < matchArray.length; i++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < matchArray.length; i++) {
                let column = columns[i];
                column.textContent = guess[i].toUpperCase();

                if (matchArray[i] === 2) {
                    column.classList.add('correct'); //perfect match
                } else if (matchArray[i] === 1) {
                    column.classList.add('in-word'); //in word, wrong spot
                } else {
                    column.classList.add('incorrect'); //no match
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function buildMatchArray(guess){
        guess = guess.toUpperCase();
        let answerAsArray = [];
        let matchArray = [0,0,0,0,0]; //assume no match to start
        for (let i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
            let letter = answer[i].toUpperCase();
            answerAsArray.push(letter);
        }
        //find exact matches
        for (let i = 0; i < guess.length; i++){
            let letter = guess[i];
            if (letter === answer[i]){
                answerAsArray[i] = null; //remove letter to prevent matching it as yellow, too
                matchArray[i] = 2 //indicate that a match was found
            }
        }
        //find in-word matches and misses
        for(let i = 0; i <guess.length; i++){
            let letter = guess[i];
            let index = answerAsArray.indexOf(letter);

            //if letter not in remaining letters, move on to next letter
            if (index === -1){
                continue
            }

            //remove letter to prevent matching in other positions
            answerAsArray[index] = null;
            //mark it yellow as it is in the word but not in the correct spot
            matchArray[i] = 1;
        }
        return matchArray
    }

</script>
</html>
```

i have an wordle html code everything seems to work fine with the english words, but the issue that i want to use arabic words and when i submit the arabic word guess i want it to print in the guessing columns from right to the left because the arabic language is written from right to left can you help me on doing that

Comment: did you try inverting the guess before checking it?

Comment: can you help me with that?